# Regular expression for an optional column

Tags: regex, text, rust

In `Rust`, with the `regex 1.0.2` library, I am using the following regular expression to read lines from a text file and store them into some datastores. The problem is that in some cases one of the column can have a missing value because is optional. However when that happens, the regex mechanism ommits the whole line. How can I inform it that the specific column is optional so that the result will recognize other parts of the line and fill the empty column with an empty string?

Example:

```
5   "Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy"   "Product"
6   "Spatial History Project"   
7   "Humanities Research Network"   "Group"`
```

Expression: `(?P<n_id>\\d+)\\s+"(?P<n_label>[^"]*)"\\s+"(?P<n_type>[^"]*)"`

Current Result :

```
Captures({0: Some("5\t\"Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy\"\t\"Product\""), "n_id": Some("5"), "n_label": Some("Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy"), "n_type": Some("Product")})
Captures({0: Some("7\t\"Humanities Research Network\"\t\"Group\""), "n_id": Some("7"), "n_label": Some("Humanities Research Network"), "n_type": Some("Group")})
```

Desirable Result:

```
Captures({0: Some("5\t\"Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy\"\t\"Product\""), "n_id": Some("5"), "n_label": Some("Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy"), "n_type": Some("Product")})
Captures({0: Some("6\t\"Spatial History Project\"\t\"Group\""), "n_id": Some("6"), "n_label": Some("Spatial History Project"), "n_type": Some("")})
Captures({0: Some("7\t\"Humanities Research Network\"\t\"Group\""), "n_id": Some("7"), "n_label": Some("Humanities Research Network"), "n_type": Some("Group")})
```

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/jm0DGc/1

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped a lot!